# Create A Batch File Within Batch File - Echo ">NUL"

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, nul

**Situation:**

- I have a text log file that gets updated frequently.
- I already have a batch file that can check it manually.
- I want it (upon start-up of batch) to create a new .bat.
- I'm having problems exporting/creating the "`timeOut /t 2 >NUL`"
  part.
- It won't export the >NUL part; leaves a blank space.
- *Example:* `timeout /t 2  /noBreak`

> I can't seem to figure out any way to export/echo out that ">NUL" snippet.. Any input would be appreciated!

```
echo mode con:cols=80 lines=28 >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo @echo off >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo Title Error Log >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo :startLogObserve >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo type %UserProfile%\Desktop\testLog.txt >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo timeout /t 2 >NUL /noBreak >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo cls >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
echo goTo :startLogObserve >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape special characters, so the parser knows which parts you want to echo and which ones you want to be executed.

Btw. It's easier to redirect a complete block

```
(
  echo mode con:cols=80 lines=28
  echo @echo off
  echo Title Error Log
  echo :startLogObserve
  echo type "%%UserProfile%%\Desktop\testLog.txt"
  echo timeout /t 2 ^>NUL /noBreak
  echo cls
  echo goTo :startLogObserve
) > %UserProfile%\Desktop\observeLog.bat
```

I also changed the `type %UserProfile%..` to `type "%%UserProfile%%..."` else you get the expanded version in your observeLog.bat
The quotes are useful when `%UserProfile%` contains spaces or special characters

Comment: For some reason when I have an echo within the block, it causes problems. It apparently executes the echo and creates a .txt file from where ever I executed the .bat file. Also, when it echos/executes, it doesn't echo out the echo to the actual "ObserveLog.bat". Sorry if this sounds confusing I'm kinda confused already right now explaining this..